# I think my data is heteroscedastic but I would like another opinion if possible?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

Thank you for looking at my question, I've been driving myself a little crazy over it today!

I have run tests for the assumption of homoscedasicity however I have been deliberating whether the formation indicates heteroscedasicity or not. I am leaning towards it does, as there is a bit of a pattern there. I also wondered if anyone had any tips for easily determining this?

I have attached an image.

[image: SPSS OUTPUT FOR HIERARCHICAL MULTIPLE REGRESSION HOMOSCEDASICITY TEST]

Comment: How many samples do you have? What model do you use?

Comment: It looks like there is a lot of overplotting in the graph, although I'm not sure. You could try making the plotting symbol smaller.

Comment: What are you trying to model here, exactly? What are your variables? The clustering and straight lines make me think that a linear regression with normal errors might be inappropriate.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to see whether the variance of your residuals varies with predicted value for your outcome then this is not the best plot to use. Try plotting predicted on the $x$-axis as you have but plot the square root of the absolute value of the residual on the $y$-axis instead of the residual. Then fit a loess line through the plot. If you have heteroscedascity the line will tend to go up with higher values of the predicted. It is much easier for the eye to see that deviation and it also gets round the problem that ranges of the predicted where you have more observations will look more variable.

In any event adding some jitter to the plot would help as there may be some over-printing here and that spoils any attempt to get a good visual impression.

Comment: +1 Also, it might help add some jitter to the resulting plot as there seems to be some quantized data that can lead to a lot of over-plotting of cases onto single points. That won't affect the loess but it might help with visualization.

Comment: @EdM good point, I have edited that in. I am a big jitter fan so not sure why I never thought of it myself, perhaps a senior moment.

Comment: That's why it helps to have more than one "senior" looking at questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know the stats guys might yell at me for this, but something I've often done is: Build another regression with the original variables except use the Residual as my dependent variable. If I get a good model, that's a problem. If the model is terrible, I'm happy. Usually this works for me when I'm identifying whether 1 variable in particular is troublesome and I'll remove it and re-train the original model without it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of regression you're doing. I suppose it's OLS regression? It does look a bit that variability decreases as predicted values increase or decrease from, something around, 20. But its hard to tell since it seems like your response is discrete (perhaps has some kind of grouping too?). Also, looks like you got reasonable amount of observations with residuals out of the (-2, 2) range. We would like to have at most only a few (<5% of) observations beyond that range. I feel that you should try a model more suitable for discrete data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a linear regression, why not use [White standard errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity-consistent_standard_errors)? It certainly looks like there's heteroscedasticity. What do your homoscdasticity tests tell you? Looking with eyes is helpful, but can also be deceiving.

Comment: [There are many good reasons to not use White standard errors, and essentially 0 to ever actually use White standard errors.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/political-analysis/article/how-robust-standard-errors-expose-methodological-problems-they-do-not-fix-and-what-to-do-about-it/7E2F393B16FC6BCD6DA8C19D8D5D1F6B) I immediately distrust any analysis using them.

Comment: @ClosedLimelikeCurves I almost didn't answer because it seems like you have very strong priors about these views, which is fine. But a polite suggestion: saying something so opinionated such as "essentially 0 reasons to ever use White standard errors" without any meaningful discussion beyond linking a single paper seems like bad practice, especially in a forum where the purpose is to have productive discussion. Heteroskedastic standard errors are used throughout disciplines, and just read the wiki page to see a very good reason to use them (namely when you have indep but diff error terms)

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by Huber-White SEs? If you just mean "using different standard errors for different categories," there's nothing wrong with that, sure. I'm specifically referring to the common practice of clustering SEs while using OLS (i.e. acknowledging clusters exist when calculating errors, but pretending they don't exist when performing the regression). This is never justified, as the paper points out, because it's just internally incoherent--the model is self-contradictory, and makes as much sense as a regression model that assumes $1=2$.

Comment: (That statistical malpractice like using Huber-White errors with OLS is common across disciplines does not make it much better.)